# How to overload an overriden method so it is called from non-overriden methods?

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, overriding, overloading

I want to override a method of a base class with multiple overloaded options, so that it can be called from a method of that base class, but only the option marked with override that matches the original signature is changed.

```kotlin
open class EgBase {
    fun lookAt(thing: Any) {
        reactTo(thing)
    }

    open fun reactTo(thing: Any) {
        println("Standard reaction")
    }
}

class EgWorkingInheritor: EgBase() {
    override fun reactTo(thing: Any) {
        println("Custom reaction")
    }
}

class EgFailingInheritor: EgBase() {
    fun reactTo(thing: Int) {
        println("Reaction for ints only!")
    }
}

fun main() {
    EgBase().lookAt(0.1) // Standard reaction
    EgWorkingInheritor().lookAt("a") // Custom reaction
    EgFailingInheritor().lookAt(7) // Standard reaction

    EgBase().reactTo(0.1) // Standard reaction
    EgWorkingInheritor().reactTo("b") // Custom reaction
    EgFailingInheritor().reactTo(2) // Reaction for ints only!
}
```

In the example provided, the second set of calls work perfectly - the overloaded method is recognised, but in the first set of calls, the EgFailingInheritor's overload of reactTo is not recognised when called from the non-overriden method. How do i get around this?

Edit: I am aware in the example it would be far better to just overload the lookAt method, but in what i am actually doing there is behaviour around the reactTo call i do not want to have to repeatedly rewrite.

Comment: Your `lookAt(Any)` calls `reactTo(Any)`, so whatever you're trying to conceive won't work and for good reasons. Only way to do it is have inheritors validate argument provided to `reactTo(Any)` and decide if they want to consume it or pass it through to `super.reactTo(Any)`.

Comment: @Pawel I know that reactTo needs to accept Any, which is why my intention was to use overloads to automatically send anything except Strings (in the example) straight through to the default implementation

Comment: Point is called method is resolved at compile time, it doesn't matter what type of argument you pass to `lookAt` it will always invoke `reactTo(Any)`. You can't make overloads magically resolve type at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `reactTo` function just for `Int`s will also fail if you use these classes in an abstract way, which is often how a class hierarchy is used:

```
val eg: EgBase = EgFailingInheritor()
eg.reactTo(2) // Standard reaction
```

You need to actually override the function you want to behave differently and manually delegate from there. This will solve both problems:

```
class EgFailingInheritor: EgBase() {
    override fun reactTo(thing: Any) {
        when (thing) {
            is Int -> reactTo(thing) // smart cast Int thing, calls overload
            else -> super.reactTo(thing)
        }
    }

    fun reactTo(thing: Int) {
        println("Reaction for ints only!")
    }
}
```